# equivaraint section descends to a section of base space

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $G$ be a Lie group action on a manifold $X$, $E$ be a equivariant $G$ vector bundle. Suppose there is a vector bundle $E_G$ over $X/G$.

**Q**： For a section $s;X\to E$, under what kind of condition, $s$ can be descended to a section of $E_G\to X/G$, by the map $X\to X/G$.

Comment: I think the only obstruction is to very that $s(g\cdot x)=s(x)$ for any $g\in G$.